# Is there any way to shout more often?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm a Dovahkiin. I can shout people to death, and it's awesome.

I lament, however, that my voice can only shout every so often, usually requiring a cooldown of 30 seconds (or more!) before I can shout again.

Is there any way to reduce the cooldown of the Thu'um? I discovered that activating a shrine of Talos offers a [Blessing of Talos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjWJ2.png) effect that reduces the time between shouts by 0%. I assume this is a bug (supposed to be 10%, perhaps?), but it makes me hopeful that other such shout reduction effects exist elsewhere in the game.

Is there anything that help me shout more often?

Comment: @JoachimSauer, Raven Dreamer does not like my humor it seems. (-1) `:(`

Comment: @NickT - you *really* think a downvote is warranted because "QUESTION ASKER DOESN'T WANT SENTENCES IN ALL CAPS"?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An Amulet of Talos will reduce the time between shouts by 20%. I believe this stacks with the +20% to shout recovery from shrines to Talos, which will knock a whopping 40% off your recovery time.

Sadly, you cannot disenchant the amulet and learn to make your own +Shout Recovery items.

Also the dragon mask Morokei (requires unofficial bugfix patch) adds another 20% getting you to 60%.

Comment: Does the Shrine of Talos buff actually do something despite being listed under Active Effects as +0%?

Comment: So, I did some research. The Talos buff has a typo in the Active Effects. It might show up as 0%, but it brings the 15 cooldown on FUS to 12, so it's clearly working. Gonna test later if it stacks.

Comment: Do these effects stack additively (20% + 20% = 40% reduction, 60% of original) or multiplicatively (20% + 20% = 0.8 * 0.8 * original = 64% of original)?

Comment: @Nellius It seems to work additively.

Answer (score 17):

The help given above - amulet and blessing of Talos plus the dragon mask Morokei for 20% reduction each.

The best reduction can be gotten if you do not use your fire breath on Paarthurnax during the quest "The throat of the world". Until you continue the quest (breath fire on the old dragon) all your shouts will have a cooldown of approx 5 secs.

Comment: Heh. Neat trick!

Answer (score 12):

There is also the [**Amulet of Talos**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVrvk.jpg), which reduces shout cooldown by 20%. One is found on the body of Roggvir who is executed the first time you visit Solitude, but you might lose it due to a quest.

[Another occasion](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615805-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/61017330) where you might find this Amulet is when you exit Ironbind Barrow after clearing it, look around at the mountain peak. It should be lying around on a statue between two chests.

[A third one](http://www.nowgamer.com/cheats/skyrim-cheats/1132444/skyrim_guide_unique_armour_and_weapons_locations.html) is Ogmund's Amulet Of Talos in Understone Keep, Markarth, The Reach. This is one of the items you can use to blackmail Ogmund during the Miscellaneous Objective 'Triumph Over Talos'.

---

[This forum thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-/61014647) shows similar behavior; are you already wearing the Amulet of Talos by accident? It might be the case that if you wear the Amulet of Talos, that the Blessing of Talos no longer has effect to prevent you from stacking both. Given that they list a reducement, it sounds like a bug...

Comment: I have two -- at least one if not both I pickpocketed from a Greybeard.

Comment: @agf: Interesting, that would indicate that they spawn on any person by a very random chance. Or, perhaps it's spawn every time on the same persons. Anyone up for confirmation?

Comment: OK, now I think there is a random chance anyone has one, like everything else. I just pickpocketed one off a Windhelm guard -- about the 10th or 15th guard I pickpocketed.

Comment: definitely random chance, I've found it on a druegar before

Comment: The greybeards having one in high hrathgar makes sense, wonder though why mavin black brier has one when you bite her or pick pocket her while she is sleeping

Comment: Kinda annoys me that I came into Solitude from the back, since I missed the execution... and people kept refering to is, as if I'd seen it...

Answer (score 6):

If we're going into outright cheat methods (such as `tgm`), you can also use the console command

```
player.setav shoutrecoverymult 0
```

to make all shout cooldowns instantaneous.

Comment: I think this is a better way to cheat more shouting. Thanks!

Comment: I've found that setting it to 0 becomes glitchy as you can't switch shouts since the game thinks its constantly recharging.  Setting it to something very low, like 0.01 works better.  I put mine at 0.2 and shouts are still nearly instant and the recovery times actually make sense (0 seconds instead of negative seconds)

Comment: turns out that glitch was because I had the blessing of talos on, with it off, setting it to 0 is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the blessing but if you go to solitude, right when you enter you will witness an execution. After the execution is over, you can go to the dead body to pick up a Amulet Of Talos, which reduces shout time by 20%. That is probably the only other think that I have been able to find so far which reduces shout recharge. I'll post again if I find anything more. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tgm` to toggle God mode, giving you unlimited shouts (no cooldown whatsoever).

The only problem with this is that, there is unlimited hp, mp, and sp,  making gaming a little "too easy". but if you want to try out "demo" of unlimited shouting (only cooldown it has is that you use your shout, the animation has to continue, and the effects has to finish in order to cast your shout again), before mods or something else pops up, there you go.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fortify_Shouts

Quoted from that page:

Enchanting description: Time between shouts is reduced 20%.

Fortify Shouts is an effect that reduces the cooldown time between shouts. The magnitude of this effect is alternatively expressed either in percentage or in points. An effect with a magnitude of 0.2 point actually causes a 20% reduction in time between shouts. A magnitude of 0.2 reduces the `ShoutRecoveryMult` actor value from its base value of 1.0 to 0.8.

Note that a display bug causes the effect text in-game to appear inaccurate in some cases. Whenever an in-game display shows the 0.2 magnitude, it rounds the value, meaning that the text ends up saying that the effect is 0% instead of 20%.

**Enchanting**

The following items use this effect, but none of them can be disenchanted:

- Amulet of Talos
- Ogmund's Amulet of Talos
- Raerek's Inscribed Amulet of Talos

**Blessings**

The Blessing of Talos reduces the time between shouts by 20%.

**Bugs**

The dragon priest mask Morokei is supposed to also have this enchantment, but due to a glitch it is never applied.

**PC Only:** This bug is fixed by version 1.1 of the Unofficial Skyrim Patch.

---

So, if you're on PC (and using the Unofficial patch), you can equip the Amulet of Talos, get the Blessing of Talos, and equip the mask for a total of 60% shout cooldown reduction.  Not bad, and no "cheating" or exploiting involved.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of the Amulet of Talos (-20%), Blessing of Talos (-20%), Dragon Aspect shout (-20%) but only usable once a day), Mask of Moreki with unofficial patch (-20%) gives a total of 80% reduced. If you don't mind being a vampire with the level 70 necromage perk you can increase the cool down of each buff to -24%. Only problem is that the unofficial patch takes that away. So for a no mod run the max would be 72% with Dragon aspect; Amulet of Talos, and Blessing of Talos. With the unofficial patch you'd max out at -80%.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with the fortify restoration potion bug you can completely take away the cooldown time also. The bug is if you have 100's of both alchemy and Smith you can basically create God like armor, weapons and potions.

- Gain the skill arcane enchanting in smithing, the first five plus extra effect in enchanting. The first five and benefactor and physician in alchemy.
- Create 4 fortify alchemy and smithing items. If you don't have the double skill perk do one of each.
- Then get the recipes for fortify enchanting, restoration, and smithing if you don't already know them.
- Then make a fortify restoration potion drink it make another stronger one.
- Then before creating your new Smith /alchemy wear take that powerful potion it will increase the strength of the the enchantment and so on then create your God like armor and weapons. As a plus, if you take the fortify restoration potion while wearing the Amulet of Talos you can negate the cool down entirely. You will not need archane enchanter unless you want to smith improved enchanted items

Comment: i would think fortify restoration behavior is considered bugged and  using it is on the same level as console command tgm

Comment: Amuelet of Talos cannot be disenchanted, right?

Answer (score 0):

I found an amulet of talos on a stormcloak body during the civil war questline (sided with imperials) and i also found various other god amulets like stendarr and that. Also only saying the first or second word of your shout usually means it will recharge faster so if you dont need the full power of a shout then dont use all of it. For example if fighting dragons and it is flying and breathing fire at you so you use the etheral shout until it lands only use the first word because you may not need the others, so be wise in your use of shouts. Other than that there is no way apart from cheating or glitching that i know of.

Answer (score 0):

Any amulet of Talos, the blessing of Talos from a shrine and the Dragon aspect shout give -60% shout timer, in the standalone with Dragonborn for that shout. I'm not sure if Morokie does give another 20% but it's meant to and mods fix that. some other mods give ways, like Cloaks of SKyrim has Greybeards Mantles you can find up in their monestary that give another -20; thats the 100 right there, and Skilltree: Speech the mod ads a perk that further reduces times, assuming you play PC, If not, 60 is still ridiculaous for Fus, and for Wuld.

Answer (score 0):

You can always have enchantments to decrease the cool-down. but if your not being attacked and doing it just for fun shouting around, you can wait 1 hour after you shout, this lets you use summoning shouts infinitely as well. you can even evade the cool-down for storm call and Odaviing shouts.

Answer (score 0):

This may be late, but you can equip an unlimited ammount of amulets by doing the werewolf trade glitch by giving your follower all of your amulets/rings/necklaces then go in to beast form and as soon as you become a silhouette, immediately talk to your follower and equip everything you traded to him/her.

Answer (score -3):

OK let me straighten this out because there is people giving false information. Morokeies dragon mask only regenerate magicka 100% so unless you have a mod for the mask to help with shouts or your just saying something for people to notice you. The only way to fortifie shouts are the amulates of Talos which you can get from bandits
And crypts. Yes even during the execution in solitude. Also if you use the word a lot the timer will cool down a lot faster. I have beaten everything on the game so I know the game inside and out.

Comment: Is there a source you can use to prove that others are giving false information?