# Skyrim Shouter build (no weapon, no spells)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to shout more often?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36422/is-there-any-way-to-shout-more-often)

I've done the full Destructive mage build and got my nice armor set that does -100% to desructive magika. And now I'm wondering is it possible to craft an armor set that has -100% Shout recharge time? So you could shout constantly...

I've seen Amulets of Talos, can they be disenchanted?

I can imagine shouting Stormcall and then Fire/Ice Breathe would make short work of most enemies. And shouting Whirlwind Sprint every second would make getting around much faster...

Comment: You cannot [disenchant the Amulet of Talos](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/36423/4239)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug where you can wear multiple pieces of equipment in the same slot, including necklaces. I did not discover this bug I just read about it (as it bends the rules by which I am willing to play the game :))

Original credit goes to Guillermo55 at the [GameFAQ's message boards](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/61142033).

A quick summary is as follows:

> 1. Gather all of your gear, in this case the amulets. Equip one and keep the others handy but not on your person.
> 2. Commit a crime and when confronted, go to jail. (Steal something cheap)
> 3. Escape from jail and do -not- get your items you were wearing.
> 4. Go to where you stashed the amulets and put another one on. Get caught again and go back to jail.
> 5. Keep doing 3-4 until you have put enough amulets on to reduce the cool down by 100% (Five amulets I believe will do this?)
> 6. Now just serve your time in jail by sleeping in the bed.
>
> When you are finally released, all the items you had equipped and then removed by being sent to jail, will be equipped again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disenchant the shout reduction effect.  The best you can do is to get the amulet of talos, talos' blessing, and [Morokei](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Morokei_%28Mask%29) (effect might need a mod to make it work as its buggy) for a total of -60%.

Even still, shout recharges take a long time, so you may want to look into this [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/38977/3917).

Even so, I'd imagine it'd be pretty hard to get around until you find one of the elemental shouts so you can do some damage, or you'll be relying on Lydia a lot.