# Can the Shrouded Gloves be disenchanted?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just started an assassin-type character in *Skyrim*, and before I put too much time into it, I wanted to confirm if the *Shrouded Gloves* can be disenchanted.

I prefer the **Nightingale** set for its slightly higher armor rating, but I also want that **2x** backstab multiplier from the *Shrouded Gloves* without losing the Matching Set perk bonus.

Answer (score 3):

[Shrouded Gloves](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Shrouded_Gloves#Shrouded_Gloves) cannot be disenchanted.  In fact, [very few attributes](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting_Effects) can.  It's usually safe to assume that if there's a unique item with a unique enchantment, it can't be disenchanted.

Comment: (anticipating a second question...) The problem with your shout plan is that you've got a global cooldown on shouts.  Using one keeps you from using *any* for an amount of time, depending on the shout and how much of it you say.  Once you advance the plot enough, you'll have a single shout that does something very comparable to dragons, however...

Comment: however, if you do want to shout a lot, this question may provide some assistance: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36422/is-there-any-way-to-shout-more-often